# Nuget update with id and version - Use latest version

Tags: powershell, nuget

Is there a way to run the the command

> nuget update -Id [PackageName] -version [VersionNumber]

and specify [VersionNumber] to update to the latest version?

I want the same behavior as this:

> nuget update -Id [PackageName]

The reason I cannot use the command without the version is that I need to support two use-cases in my build scripts with one command:

- Update to a specific version.
- Update to the latest version.

There exists this sub-optimal solution:

> nuget update -Id [PackageName] [AdditionalParameter]

Either setting [AdditionalParameter] to "" to "-version 'x.x.x.x'"

What I am trying to achieve is something like the following:

> nuget update -Id [PackageName] -version "latest"
>
> nuget update -Id [PackageName] -version "(,100.0)"

However, this is not valid syntax.

Comment: Why not add a conditional check in the script? If a version is specified run with the version parameter and if not run without.

Comment: Good question. I forgot to mention an important point. I am currently using a predefined build step to run nuget and can only modify the parameter. If I go for a conditional check I would need to abandon the predefined step and replace it with a custom script as a build step.